# Как спарсить информацию с двух тегов и записать в одну переменную(в порядке получения данных)?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

```
changes = soup.find_all('div', class_='finance-currency-table__cell finance-currency-table__cell--change finance-currency-table__cell--up')
changes_ = soup.find_all('div', class_='finance-currency-table__cell finance-currency-table__cell--change finance-currency-table__cell--down')
```

Не так: '''changes.extend(changes_)'''

https://finance.rambler.ru/currencies/ На всякий случай

Comment: уточните что именно вы хотите видеть в результате

Answer (score 0):

Например, Вы можете использовать такой код:

```
changes = soup.find_all('div', class_='finance-currency-table__cell finance-currency-table__cell--change finance-currency-table__cell--up')
changes_ = soup.find_all('div', class_='finance-currency-table__cell finance-currency-table__cell--change finance-currency-table__cell--down')

data = []
for change in changes:
    data.append(change.text)
for change_ in changes_:
    data.append(change_.text)

print(data)
```

Мы создаём список `data`, в который добавляем элементы в порядке их получения. В результате, `data` будет содержать информацию из обоих тегов в порядке их получения.

Comment: В итоге, я сделал это благодаря совпадению слов в классах:

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, поставьте голос "За" на мой ответ :)